# overloading onResume()

Tags: java, android

How to overload `onResume()` to work the correct way? I want to come back from `activity` to `MainActivity` where I want to have the same state as after app start. I wanted to use `recreate()` but it looped or some sort of that.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    recreate();
}
```

Comment: "I want to come back from activity to MainActivity where I want to have the same state as after start app". Elaborate? Are you spawning another Activity that you want to kill and go back to your Main? Or what is is you actually want?

Comment: @webuster Yes, Activity could be killed, but most important think is to reload, refresh all MainActivity values ect.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it would be hard to tell you why exactly you are looping. One thing to look out for is that onResume() is called after onCreate() when the app is first opened. Meaning you may be calling recreate() when you aren't expecting.

Comment: Well, why not save the values/data you need and update/restore them as necessary after calling `super.onResume()` just as you would initialize your Activity? Thing is, after you spawn your new Activity (the one that shadows your Main), your MainActivity state should not change, so maybe I need more info on what you need.

Comment: @natez0r It was after onCreate. I paste it before onCreate and nothing has changed

Comment: @webuster i don't need any data to be restored, that's the fine thing. The Activity is executing finish(); and return to MainActivity which i want to reload recreate, re anything that couse the same efect as onCreate().

Comment: I didn't mean physically in the file, I meant that in the android lifecycle. You should read the docs about it. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: @natez0r so what is your advice in my case ?

Comment: My advice would be that you shouldn't do your recreate() in onResume(), it shouldn't be necessary as long as you activity is kept in memory. If it's being killed and you're losing state, you can save important state in onSaveInstance() state and read it again in onCreate(Bundle). You could also use startActivityForResult() to start your activity and your MainActivity will get a call to onActivityResult() rather than just onResume() when it's returned to.

Comment: @natez0r i write it all. I've got static list and if list.size()>0 then button shows up. after click on button im going to next activity that displays all item from that static list. Then i delete list items by click on it. while list is empty i call finish(). Guess what, despite static list is empty, button is still visible. That is why i want to refresh it somehow, to delete button.

Comment: I would caution the use of static variables being shared across the activities like this. You could consider storing the list in a shared preference and reading that preference onResume()

Answer (score 1):

implement `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle save)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle restore)` to save and restore the state. See [the documentation on this.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Comment: and it will erase button ?

Comment: Hard to tell. Your question is not very clear, but I was trying to point you at the documentation on how to manage state in an android Activity.

In general the state of an activity should be preserved in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle save)` and restored in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle restore)`. So if you want to have a button that has two states you might do `save.putBoolen('buttonVisible', mButtonVisible)` in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle save)` and `setButtonVisible(restore.getBoolean("buttonVisible", false))` in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle restore)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, when you press back button, you want to refresh the previous activity.

It is pretty simple, you can just put your method in onResume(), and it should do the trick.

Comment: I don't understand what method should put in onResurme() ?

Comment: do you just want to refresh the previous activity?? If yes, then I will make some example??

Comment: Hey can you like my answer if i helped you out. I will need your help by liking my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok Try this out, it is working for me.

```
public class main extends Activity{


   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

   //add any buttons or anything you have here.
         doMainWork(); \\lets just say you have this method, which contains the main code of the layout.
   }


   protected void onResume(){
         super.onResume();
         doMainWork();
   }

   public void doMainWork(){

       \\Put all your working code here. And this should work it out man. 
   }
```

Comment: Work, but button is still visible

Comment: You should have edited your existing answer. This way you get two not very good answers. I suggest you move contents of this answer to the original one and delete this one.

Comment: Button?? Buddy you didn't mention anything about button?? What kinda button it is?

Comment: @Palec, my example is just for references. It meant to replace the existing code.